# Change the default tab of the re-open queue to 'Revision'

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen

When reviewing in the reopen votes queue, I personally have found that the Revision (highlighted differences) tab is by far the most useful in efficiently casting a vote.  Often they are just grammar changes to old posts, which show up really clearly in this view.

It may well be just me who finds this, but if others are constantly switching to the Revision tab first to see changes before swapping back if necessary perhaps the default tab could be changed.

**Example:**
[image: First tab view]

*The post has been edited, in this view I have to read both questions to see if the duplicate issue has been addressed*.

[image: Revisions tab view]

*However in the Revisions view it is very quickly evident that there are only formatting changes made and no re-open vote should be cast.*

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but the post having been edited is not really a criteria for evaluation, but merely a way to understand why a post was closed in the first place.  The current revision can always be evaluated on its own merit, irrespective of any previous versions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree it can, however if it's a long post and the only changes are spelling/grammar then reading through the current revision is usually a big waste of time.  Hence the swapping of tabs.  If the Revisions tab was default, it would much more quickly become apparent if the edit was substantial enough to *possibly* warrant reopening, whereupon we could then switch to the current post view to evaluate it in full.

Comment: How about showing them side by side, like suggested edits?