# Proposed change to close question reviews for exact duplicates

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

Lately, I started reviewing close votes (I got the required rep! hurray!).

I believe it would significantly assist the reviewing process if for the "exact duplicates" suggestions, the screen were split to show the question under review (the dup) **alongside** the question that is supposed to be the original question.

This split screen, I imagine, would be rather similar to the split screen used for reviewing suggested edits.

Comment: I agree and this is also a similar [feature-request to showing revisions for the reopen-queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165273/change-the-default-tab-of-the-re-open-queue-to-revision). Basically, to sum it all up - show the reason for why the item is in the queue in the first place. Don't hide it behind a second tab. =D